# Is it possible to generate pie chart for a single column based on their values?

Tags: excel, charts

My excel spreadsheet is shown below:

[image]

I generated pie chart for the GEN column which is shown below.

[image]

My problem is that the pie chart is based on the number of rows. I want to get pie chart only for GEN column so that my pie chart shows only the belonging two values (1 and 2) and both occupying 50-50% of the total pie chart area.

Comment: You didn't get the question IMHO. If you HAD 1,2,2,2 should the chart then be 25% and 75%?

Comment: yes..thats what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You should select as Y Values of your chart the 1s and the 2s in the interested column separately.
Open an empty pie chart and select "choose data", then select "add" and highlight your "1" as a first selection. Hold then Ctrl and select your "2".

Comment: Edited my answer. You can also use the legend to describe your "1" and "2" by unchecking unnecessary "horizontal describers" and renaming the remaining ones